# Conflict with CNAME wildcard with child CNAME

Tags: cname-record, dns-zone, powerdns

I migrated from PowerDNS to Knot 2.7.

I have a conflict with 2 DNS records now.

```
abcd.**www**.example.com CNAME -> somehost.example.net
*.example.com -> example.com
```

Now the problem is with the  www.example.com domain. In PowerDNS it was to resolve as *.example.com. Now there's no response. When I add A or CNAME record for www.example.com all is ok. Problem is based on first CNAME as I wrote above.

Can you explain me why and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour that you describe is entirely expected; what I find surprising is the claim that you got a different result with PowerDNS (you may want to file a bug report if you can reproduce this with a current version).

The reason why this is the expected behaviour is that wildcard functionality in DNS is defined in such a way that the wildcard only expands to names that *do not exist* below the wildcard entry (ie, essentially names where you would otherwise get an `NXDOMAIN` response).

What may not feel intuitive here is that with the two records in the question, the name `www.example.com` is considered to *exist* (even though it doesn't have any records of its own) because it is an intermediate node in the branch that leads to `abcd.www.example.com` (which does have records). (This type of intermediate tree node without records is referred to as an *empty non-terminal* or *ENT*).
As the name `www.example.com` exists, it follows from the definition of how wildcards work that it should not be affected by `*.example.com` and you will get a `NODATA` response (indicated by `NOERROR` status with `SOA` in the authority section) unless you add records to `www.example.com` itself.